# Сложить эллементы многоуровнего массива

Tags: php, laravel

Есть такой массив

```
  [
    0 => [
           0 => "xs"
           1 => "s"
           2 => "m"
         ]
    1 => [
           0 => "red"
           1 => "blue"
         ]
  ]
```

Как то нужно динамически сложить вложенные массивы, что бы получилось вот так

```
[
  0 => "xs"
  1 => "red"
]
[
  0 => "s"
  1 => "red"
]
[
  0 => "m"
  1 => "red"
]
[
  0 => "xs"
  1 => "blue"
]
[
  0 => "s"
  1 => "blue"
]
[
  0 => "m"
  1 => "blue"
]
```

Как это можно сделать функциями для работы с массивами, или на коллекциях (ларавел)

Comment: А что что должно получиться если в исходном массиве будет 3+ элемента а не 2?

Comment: @E_p дублироваться

Comment: Не совсем понял. Пример приведите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В примере почему то не указан вариант, что будет если в исходном массиве будет 3 и более элементов, как нужно складывать данные.

**Вот что получилось.**

Вдруг придёт такая портянка:

```
$a = [
    0 => [
        0 => "xs",
        1 => "s",
        2 => "m",
    ],
    1 => [
        0 => "red",
        1 => "blue",
        2 => "navy"
    ],
    2 => [
        0 => "red1",
        1 => "blue1"
    ],
    3 => [
        0 => "red2",
        1 => "blue2",
        2 => "green2",
        3 => "yellow2"
    ],
    4 => [
        0 => "red3",
        1 => "blue3",
        2 => "green3"
    ]
];
```

Рассчитаем оставшиеся элементы и сложим их в один кулачок

```
function start($a,$index){
    $c = [];
    foreach($a as $i=>$b){
        if($i > $index) $c = array_merge($c,$b);
    }
    return $c;
}
```

А это сам генератор пар, калькулятор слов и тд

```
function generate($a){
    $matrix = [];
    foreach($a as $i=>$b){
        $d = start($a,$i);
        foreach($b as $c) array_walk($d, function($x)use($c,&$matrix){$matrix[] = [$c,$x];});
    }
    return $matrix; 
}
```

Comment: (1/1) ErrorException
array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array

Comment: покажи какой массив засовываешь?

Comment: С этим разобрался. теперь ругается на этот код `$matrix[] = "{$c}->{$x}";` -  `Array to string conversion`

Comment: покажи массив свой

Comment: Все,я разобрался. Спасибо большое!. В конце выходит такой массив `array:6 [
  0 => "XS->Red"
  1 => "XS->Blue"
  2 => "S->Red"
  3 => "S->Blue"
  4 => "M->Red"
  5 => "M->Blue"
]`

Comment: Ну и хорошо. Обращайся)

Comment: я извиняюсь. А можно как нибудь сделать что бы в конце получился такой массив `array:6 [ 0 => [0 => "XS", 1 => "Red"] 1 => [0 => "XS", 1 => "Blue"]]`

Comment: Исправил код, смотри

Comment: Блин, с этим изменением он делает правильный массив, но теперь только с последним размером. Вот сейчас я выбрал размеры XS, S, M , XL, и цвета  Red, Blue, Green. По идеи он должен был сделать 15 комбинаций, и 2 варианта на 1 комбинацию. А он вот что сделал: `Collection {#419
  #items: array:3 [
    0 => array:2 [
      0 => "XL"
      1 => "Red"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [
      0 => "XL"
      1 => "Blue"
    ]
    2 => array:2 [
      0 => "XL"
      1 => "Green"
    ]
  ]
}` Только с последним размером.

Comment: XS, S, M, L, XL* L забыл написать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63258/discussion-between-eldario-and-alex-01).

Answer (score 0):

Чисто процедурно можете сделать циклами.

```
function newFunc ($firstArray, $secondArray) {
    foreach ($firstArray as $val1) {
       foreach ($secondArray as $val2) {
           $result [] = [$val1, $val2];
       }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Функция рекурсивно нагенерит массив массивов, где по порядку создаст все вариации объединения значения из первого массива со всеми значениями второго массива.

Comment: этот варриант не подходит, тк заранее неизвестно сколько подмассивов в исходном массиве. Сейчас 2, а может быть и 3 и 4